# Magento 2 : How to validate email or mobile number in a textbox validation

Tags: magento2, email, validation, mobile

```
  <input type="text" class="input-email-mobile " id="customer-email-mobile">
```

I need to validate Mobile number or email  in the above text box using magento validation.! maybe the user enter mobile number or email in the same input  `data-validate="{required:true,'validate-email':true,'validate-number':true}`this code only validate email. how can i achieve both in a text box using magento validation In Checkout Shipping Address page ??

Comment: if you take a look here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/web/mage/validation.js#L614-L619 you will see the email validation checks for @domain.com structure.  As telephone would never contain this you are going to fail this validation but will be entering a perfectly valid telephone number.  In short I don't think it can be done.

Comment: this issue solved or ?

Comment: hai @RohanHapani. this  issue not solved

Comment: Is it working for you? @ShafeelSha

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 uses **validation.js** file for apply validations which is located at `lib/web/mage` directory of Magento 2.

In Magento 2, it's not by default provide rule which validate mobile number and email ID validate in textbox.

**So, Need to create new rule to extend validation.js using mixin.**

1) create **requirejs-config.js** at `app/code/RH/CustomValidation/view/frontend/`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'RH_CustomValidation/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Now, Add the JS validation class using the mixin at `app/code/RH/CustomValidation/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        var custom_text;
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-custom-mob-email-rule',
            function (value) {
                var mob_regex = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/;
                var email_regex = /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/;
                if (!$.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(value))
                {
                    if(email_regex.test(value) && !mob_regex.test(value)){
                        return true;
                    } else if(mob_regex.test(value) && !email_regex.test(value)){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

3) Now, change class name in **login.phtml** file. Find "Email" Text field. Then, change field type email to text and replace **validate-email** validation with **validate-custom-mob-email-rule** new validation.

Now, upgrade, deploy and clean cache.

Cheers :)

Comment: hai @Rohan Hapani  , now its working only in email validation

Comment: You must need to add mobile number like +911234567890

Comment: already trying but no changes ,  after upgrade my project the validation fields shows *data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"* my custom rule not visible here and all input  attributes related to email  ?

Comment: As I said, you need to override login.phtml file in your module/theme.

Comment: yes sir , already i'm using my custom module and .html file here is my file path *app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html*

Comment: Then, remove 'validate-email':true  and add this line : 'validate-custom-mob-email-rule':true in your phtml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96793/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-rohan-hapani).